# Loop vibration in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, avplayer, vibration

I'm playing a sound using AVPlayer. I'm trying to let the iPhone vibrate during this sound. 
I'm able to create a vibration with:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

But I'm having **problems trying to loop this vibration** if I use:

```
vibrationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.loopVibration), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func loopVibration() {
      AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

The func *loopVibration*() gets called every two seconds but it **doesn't vibrate**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this isn't working for you--the following sample works for me on my test device (iPhone X, iOS 11.2).

The ViewController sample below includes outlets for playing single sounds, playing single vibrations, looping sounds and looping vibrations. The "Chirp" sound is a 1s wav file.

Note that since this is a sample, the code below doesn't dispose of the system sounds, nor invalidate timers if the ViewController is hidden. Make sure to manage your system resources appropriately if you adapt this.

```swift
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static let soundId: SystemSoundID? = {
        guard let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Chirp", withExtension: "wav") else {
            return nil
        }

        var soundId: SystemSoundID = 0
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL as CFURL, &soundId)
        return soundId
    }()

    static let timerInterval: TimeInterval = 2

    var soundTimer: Timer?
    var vibrationTimer: Timer?
    var playCount = 0 {
        didSet {
            playCountLabel.text = String(playCount)
        }
    }

    func invalidateTimers() {
        if let vibrationTimer = vibrationTimer {
            vibrationTimer.invalidate()
        }
        if let soundTimer = soundTimer {
            soundTimer.invalidate()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var playCountLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func playSound(_ sender: Any) {
        if let soundId = ViewController.soundId {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId)
            playCount += 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func loopSound(_ sender: Any) {
        invalidateTimers()
        soundTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: ViewController.timerInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(playSound(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func vibrate(_ sender: Any) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
        playCount += 1
    }

    @IBAction func loopVibrate(_ sender: Any) {
        invalidateTimers()
        soundTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: ViewController.timerInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(vibrate(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func cancelAll(_ sender: Any) {
        invalidateTimers()
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the problem is because I'm using the mic in the background. Thank you for the answer. Since it would get rejected I will not use this approach!

Comment: @Palpatim - Tried your solution.  The vibration works on my iPhone X.  The sound doesn't.  Neither work on the iPad 6th generation running iOS 11.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

It's not permitted to use continuous vibration, your app might be rejected. If you still want to do it you can try something like this:

```
func vibrate() {
    for i in 0...13 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(Double(i) * 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: {
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
            self.vibrate()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe Apple's docs regarding no looping ("Looping and stereo positioning are unavailable") are referring to the Media player looping functionality. However, your point about continuous vibration (or system sounds) getting the app rejected is a good one--Apple is likely to be unhappy with the user experience that a continuous repeating vibration provides.